# How to start inferior-lisp and swank both together

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, swank-clojure

I am doing both clojure and clojurescript development. I usually start clojure by the clojure-jack-in function, and clojurescript repl by the following funciton -

```
(defun clojurescript-repl ()
 (interactive)
 (run-lisp "lein2 trampoline cljsbuild repl-listen"))
```

The clojure-jack-in starts swank while the above function starts inferior-lisp. However both of them have same key bindings. How do I change the key bindings to use both of them at once?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there isn't a great way to do this.

The Clojurescript One wiki has some pointers tho:

https://github.com/brentonashworth/one/wiki/Emacs